# JFrame does not appear when using while statement

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I wanted the game to keep looping until the `GameOver` is false.

I used to do it with an if but the game wasn't really looping so I used a while statement. But after I try to compile it my `JFrame` wouldn't appear at all! Nothing appeared in fact.

Any possible solutions as to how to fix this?

```
public void game() {
    while (GameOver != true) {
        ATT1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (b.Death == false) {
                    a.Att1(b, Fireball);
                } else {
                    a.Att1(c, Fireball);
                }
            }
        });
        ATT2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (b.Death == false) {
                    a.Att2(b, Fireball);
                } else {
                    a.Att2(c, Fireball);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you add so many actionlisteners? Isn't one of each enough?

Comment: Make sure your loop doesn't run in the swing thread.  You only show a fragment of the code here so it is impossible to know what's wrong

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40562837/edit) your question and add a [MCVE] or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). The snippet you added does not show enough for us to help you. GL!

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. If you cannot solve it from that advice, do as suggested by @TT. & post an MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

And most probably if you check the system statistics CPU usage chart will rocket into the skies right?

It is because you are starting a long running loop with no time consuming actions in it, resulting in many executions in a short time (thus CPU load). I bet that you call `game()` from within another action listener right? (maybe after pushing a "Start game" button)

I think that your approach to GUI code is wrong due to lack of knowledge on how Swing based applications work. It is far different and more complex from structural programming because of the introduction of concurrency. You are blocking the EDT (lets say GUI thread) resulting in frame not being drawn correctly.

Start with reading Oracle's guide onto how to build Swing apps that you can find here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/